# Backend verification of hash code in android auto read of OTP sms

Tags: android, react-native, sms, android-sms

As mentioned in https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/verify#computing_your_apps_hash_string

The valid sms OTP verification message looks like -

```
Your ExampleApp code is: 123ABC78


FA+9qCX9VSu
```

The encoded hash code FA+9qCX9VSu is being generated from app via class [AppSignatureHelper](https://github.com/googlearchive/android-credentials/blob/master/sms-verification/android/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/smartlock/sms_verify/AppSignatureHelper.java) and sent from app to backend to be retrieved in SMS.The OTP sms  is auto read and working fine .

There are many cases in which the hashcode recieved is not what app would generate (e.g.CI427IRTSPC) and seems to be from fishy/malicious source .

**Is there any way by which backend code can validate obtained hashcode ?**